# Javascript check for multiple parent tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have built a very simple `contenteditable` editor, which allows the following:

1. A:links
2. H1, H2 tags
3. Bold, Italic and Underline

The above is all done via `document.execCommand` and works fine. My problem is checking `onmousedown`/`up` if the focused area has parent tags (one or more).

I have managed to write a function that will check and update my editor's CSS if specific tags are present. But this doesn't account for more than one tag, I'm sure there must be a simple way of doing this and I'm overlooking something.

My code so far (currently looking for one tag only):

```
document.onmousedown = triggerTextSelection;
document.onmouseup = function (event) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        check(event);
    }, 1);
};

function check() {
    // The same applies for Bold,Italic,Underline etc...
    if (hasParentWithTag(getFocusNode(), 'blockquote')) {
        $('.quote-btn').addClass('btn-active');
    } else {
        $('.quote-btn').removeClass('btn-active');
    }
}

function getFocusNode() {
    return document.getSelection().focusNode;
}

function hasParentWithTag(node, nodeType) {
    while (node.parentNode) {
        if (node.nodeName.toLowerCase() === nodeType) {
            return true;
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Can you make jsFiddle testcase?

Comment: you could use jqeury .parents(nodeType) to know if some ancestor is from the given tag : http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking if the nodeName is equal to the nodeType, you can create an array of nodeTypes against which you want to test and then check if the nodeName is in the array

Comment: Thanks for the comment @user1990021, I thought i could do the following: 
while(node.parentNode) { var check = node.nodeName.toLowerCase(); var myArray = ['bolc', 'italic']; if($.inArray(check, myArray)!== -1){ /* Do your thing */}} But this seems to throw an error whilst loading the page... Any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: @LeeMarshall what is the error you are getting? you can define myArray before the while loop, there's no need to recreate it

Comment: @LeeMarshall Did you forget to call node = node.parentNode inside the while loop? If so, then you get an infinite loop

Comment: You are right, i added that which prevented the error... Its still only recognising/displaying one... So if its a bold block quote it stating Blockquote.

Comment: @LeeMarshall Now the code should go inside the if block for every ancestor of focusNode that has the tag inside the array. Could you post the modified code? Btw, I think you placed 'bolc' in your array instead of 'bold'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40645/discussion-between-user1990021-and-lee-marshall)